# Creating MSSQL Stored Procedure to check TableA record count. Then insert TableA records to TableB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hoping someone can give me a general example of how to do the following in MSSQL 2008/2005

I need to do the following in 1 stored procedure.

I need it to verify TableA has more than 1 record. 
If TableA has more than one record then:

Delete all records from TableB AND copy the records from TableA to TableB

For the sake of argument and/or simplicity TableA and TableB  Schemes are the same

This task wouldn't be that hard if I was performing the tasks in VB but I am trying to offload this work to the SQL server  and I am not familiar on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
 CREATE PROC DoStuff
 AS 

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA) > 1
    BEGIN

         DELETE TableB;
         INSERT INTO TableB (ID, CustomerName) 
             SELECT ID, CustomerName
             FROM TableA;
    END
```

Comment: @Kardsen: you're welcome; remember to use the green checkmark (and up-vote) on all your questions to the answers that helped you the most. It's part of the reputation system on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at SQL Server integration services.  It is designed to perform exactly the types of tasks you are trying to do.

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

- http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.com/2010/11/incremental-load-using-ssis-package.html
- http://vsteamsystemcentral.com/cs21/blogs/applied_business_intelligence/archive/2007/05/21/ssis-design-pattern-incremental-loads.aspx

These go over using an Incremental Load which seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks.  The whole idea behind what I am doing is that there is another server that holds all open ticket data which I need to query off of for Web Based Reporting.  The problem is that the origin table is flaky.  It goes down for hours if not day(s) at a time.  So I keep a local copy on my server and update the results when they are available.  The table usually only consists of 3000-4000 records.   I'll definately look at the SSIS though as it may prove useful in some other automation I want to do.